# Angular 2 npm install globally (how to install package globally so no need to run every time npm install command)

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install

AngularJS2

How to install a package globally? In `Angular 2` npm installs globally.

In that every time I need to run `npm install` (on the basis of `package.json`) and it is very time consuming can you help me how to installed a package globally so every time I can refer that path and no need to run `npm install` command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do it, but I personally, don't think it's a good idea to keep everything installed globally.

> npm install -g

Comment: But if i run this command and again creating new project ... ng serve command(application is not getting launch) is not working properly

Comment: Then I guess it's really better to keep packages locally, because not all of them are compatible with the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

The global package is just for the cli tool. `NPM install` is to keep your project up-to-date. I think the only way to do this is to install it in a specific folder then copy the hold folder to anywhere you want although it's not a good idea!

If nothing unusual, things would go right!